# How to allow null on foreign key column in mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql, null, foreign-keys

I have mysql table `users`. In the registration form country is compulsory but district is not compulsory. Both are foreign key column.

So some user keep empty the district field.
Than what & how should i pass `district_id` from ajax, if district is blank?

I have already set null the `district_id` null & passing "null" value for `district_id` column.
But error is incorrect integer value for `district_id` column.

Pls. suggest an idea.

Comment: Please Show an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

If table field is already checked with "NULL" property, is just you not pass any value to this column

Answer (score 0):

a primary key cannot be null. You can create a "special" record in district table to represent a value when there is not value setted from user.